# Is there a global online resource for campsites?

Tags: online-resources, camping

I'm wondering if there's any website which covers either the whole world or possibly a major part of Europe listing campsites, ideally with ratings, bookings, maps, pricing, availability.

Something combining some features of Hostel World, Trip Advisor, Couch Surfing, but focused on camping.

Does such a thing exist?

(I'm in Bulgaria heading either to southern Serbia or the Republic of Macedonia and then through Albania and it would be great to be able to route my way through areas I can camp in my tent. Besides it seems like a great idea somebody must've had by now!)

Comment: Not an answer because it only covers Serbia and is only a Google Map but today that was just what I needed: http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?hl=en&ie=UTF8&t=h&source=embed&msa=0&msid=210137172425047101062.00049a6eb177a0e46e1b6&ll=44.512176,21.09375&spn=3.917157,8.55835&z=7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ADAC (Allgemeiner Deutscher Automobil Club), the german automobile club, features a series of guides, that covers thousands of campgrounds in whole Europe. Each campground is shortly described, rated, and the facilities as well as the prices are listed.

[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3899057759) is an example of the actual guide that covers Germany and Scandinavia.

I used these books a lot in Scandinava, Southern Europe and Eastern Europe and it was really useful. [There is also a online version of this guide](http://campingfuehrer.adac.de/home/index.php), but is not as detailed as the books.

Comment: I am asking specifically about online resources. The ADAC one seems like a nice start. Too bad it doesn't list anything in my area now.

Comment: That's a pitty, but it is the only online ressource I'm aware of. Maybe it is possible to get an online copy of the books?

Comment: Well it's not global but it seems to be the single source with the greatest coverage so I'll accept this.

Answer (score 5):

For the UK, there are a couple of online resources:

- **[Camping Ninja](http://www.campingninja.com/)**: A listing of camping sites around the UK run by camping enthusiasts. This site relies on campsite owners adding listings so you may not find all options but on the bright site it's an extremely well-designed website.
- **[Cool Camping](http://www.coolcamping.co.uk/)**: Compiled list of camping sites.
- **[Camping and Caravaning Club](http://www.campingandcaravanningclub.co.uk/)**: Perhaps not what you're looking for, this is a requires membership to join and seems to be geared towards a more sanitised, 'family' camping experience.

Comment: That Ninja site is exactly what I was looking for. Too bad they don't cover the whole world.

Comment: I smell here another business idea ;)

Answer (score 5):

While no-one has posted a good global site yet, here are resources for Nordic / Scandinavian countries. (All these sites are available in English too.)

- **Finland**: [camping.fi](http://www.camping.fi/template_page1.asp?sua=2&lang=3&s=528&q=y) seems to be a comprehensive resource.
- **Sweden**: likewise with [camping.se](http://www.camping.se/templates/start____320.aspx).
- **Norway**: ditto with [camping.no](http://www.camping.no/index_eng.html). (Do I see a pattern here..?)
- **Denmark**: try [dk-camp.dk](http://www.dk-camp.dk/default.asp?lanGuid=3).
- **Iceland**: this page seems pretty good: [visiticeland.com/Accommodation/Camping](http://visiticeland.com/Accommodation/Camping/).

I also came across [**EuroCampings.eu**](http://www.eurocampings.eu) which covers most of Europe! With a quick look, it's pretty comprehensive and all (e.g. in case of Finland, camping.fi has 136 camping sites and EuroCampings 132). According to the site, they list 9100 camp sites in 29 countries.